# How do I arrange the data by different WHERE conditions into different columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, pivot

I have a table that have 3 columns (SID,SUBJECT,MARKS):

```
╔══════╦═════════╦═══════╗
║ SID  ║ SUBJECT ║ MARKS ║
╠══════╬═════════╬═══════╣
║ 1A01 ║ ENG     ║    66 ║
║ 1A02 ║ ENG     ║    75 ║
║ 1A01 ║ MATH    ║    60 ║
║ 1A03 ║ ENG     ║    73 ║
║ 1A02 ║ MATH    ║    35 ║
║ 1A03 ║ MATH    ║    80 ║
║ 1A01 ║ CHI     ║    65 ║
║ 1A02 ║ CHI     ║    74 ║
║ 1A03 ║ CHI     ║    78 ║
╚══════╩═════════╩═══════╝
```

And I want to group the data by the SID in each row like:

```
╔══════╦═════╦═════╦══════╗
║ SID  ║ CHI ║ ENG ║ MATH ║
╠══════╬═════╬═════╬══════╣
║ 1A01 ║  65 ║  66 ║   60 ║
║ 1A02 ║  74 ║  75 ║   35 ║
║ 1A03 ║  78 ║  73 ║   80 ║
╚══════╩═════╩═════╩══════╝
```

I am new in mysql, I tried to use subquery and UNION but it failed.
Can anyone please give me some hints?

Comment: See pivot tables - [MySQL pivot tables (transform rows to columns)](http://buysql.com/mysql/12-how-to-pivot-tables.html), [Pivot table basics: rows to columns](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78), [Dynamic pivot tables](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html).

Answer (score 5):

If those 3 are the only subjects, you can use `CASE` to test the `Subject` for every `SID` and aggregate the result using `MAX()`.

```
SELECT  SID,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Subject = 'Chi' THEN Marks ELSE NULL END) `Chi`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Subject = 'Eng' THEN Marks ELSE NULL END) `Eng`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Subject = 'Math' THEN Marks ELSE NULL END) `Math`
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY SID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44443/1)

But if you have unknown number of subjects, then a *Dynamic SQL* which uses `PREPARE` is much preferred.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN Subject = ''',
      Subject,
      ''' then Marks end) AS ',
      CONCAT('`', Subject,'`')
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM TableName;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT  SID, ', @sql, ' 
                    FROM    TableName
                    GROUP   BY SID');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44443/4)

**OUTPUT** from both query

```
╔══════╦═════╦═════╦══════╗
║ SID  ║ CHI ║ ENG ║ MATH ║
╠══════╬═════╬═════╬══════╣
║ 1A01 ║  65 ║  66 ║   60 ║
║ 1A02 ║  74 ║  75 ║   35 ║
║ 1A03 ║  78 ║  73 ║   80 ║
╚══════╩═════╩═════╩══════╝
```